# Query two tables and replace values from one table in the second one

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have two tables like so:

`fruits`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 2 | Orange |
| 3 | Pear |

`users`

| id | name | fruit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 3 |
| 2 | Bob | 2 |
| 3 | Adam | 1 |

I would like to query both of those tables and in the result get user ID, his name and a fruit name (fruit ID in users table corresponds to the ID of the fruit) like so:

| id | name | fruit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Pear |
| 2 | Bob | Orange |
| 3 | Adam | Apple |

I tried joining those two with a query below with no success so far.

```
SELECT * FROM users, fruits WHERE fruits.id = fruit;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` the fruit table like this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, f.name FROM users u JOIN fruits f ON u.fruit = f.id
```

See a working example [**here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/79438/2)

Comment: Can we modify the query to also include records where a certain user does not have a fruit ID specified? The above query only returns matching rows. If a user does not have a fruit the query should still return this row with a NULL in the "name" column. Does that make sense?

Comment: You need to use `LEFT JOIN`, see this updated fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/79438/6

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.id,a.name,b.name as fruit
from users a
join friuts b
on b.id=a.fruit
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.name FROM 
    users a JOIN fruits b 
    ON a.fruit = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, f.name 
FROM users u 
inner join fruits f 
ON f.id = u.fruit
```