# Include null rows when querying with JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have two tables: `FRUITS` and `USERS`.

```
fruits
-------------
id | name   |
-------------
1  | Apple  |
2  | Orange |
3  | Pear   |
-------------

users
-------------------
id | name | fruit |
-------------------
1  | John | 3     |
2  | Bob  | 2     |
3  | Adam | 1     |
-------------------
```

I use the below query (answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074642/query-two-tables-and-replace-values-from-one-table-in-the-second-one)) to query users with a proper fruit name instead of just fruit `ID`:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, f.name FROM users u JOIN fruits f ON u.fruit = f.id
```

However the above query only returns users with a valid fruit `ID`. How to modify this query to also return users with invalid/empty fruit `ID`? That way fruit name should be `NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a 'LEFT JOIN':

> SELECT
>       u.id
>       ,u.name
>       ,f.name FROM
>       users u
>       LEFT JOIN fruits f ON    u.fruit = f.id

Comment: All answers where correct but accepting Patrick's answer as he's new to SO ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use `left join`

```
SELECT 
u.id, 
u.name, 
f.name 
FROM users u  
LEFT JOIN fruits f ON u.fruit = f.id
```

Answer (score 2):

You would use a `left join`:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, f.name
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     fruits f
     ON u.fruit = f.id;
```

This will keep all rows in the `users` table, even those with non-matching values in `fruits`.

Comment: haha so fast not giving time to type ;). just what i want to suggest.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, f.name FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN fruits f ON u.fruit = f.id
```

Read about `LEFT JOIN` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp).